# How to override server.xml file fo tomcat from spring project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, tomcat8, server.xml

How can I override server.xml or context.xml file of tomcat 8 from project? Because I am using data source in server.xml.

Comment: It is certainly possible in case of embedded Tomcat: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791514/spring-boot-tomcat-configuration-migration-from-container-to-embedded

Answer (score 2):

You cannot override the server.xml from your project. On the other hand you can override context.xml. You can do so by ([c/p from docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html))

> In an individual file at /META-INF/context.xml inside the application
>   files. Optionally (based on the Host's copyXML attribute) this may be
>   copied to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ and renamed to
>   application's base file name plus a ".xml" extension.

As described, to override context.xml you should add a META-INF to your webapp's root and place inside your context.xml. Note that in order for your projects context.xml to take effect, there should not be already set context.xml for that particular project inside tomcat instance

> In individual files (with a ".xml" extension) in the
>   $CATALINA_BASE/conf/[enginename]/[hostname]/ directory. The context
>   path and version will be derived from the base name of the file (the
>   file name less the .xml extension). This file will always take
>   precedence over any context.xml file packaged in the web application's
>   META-INF directory.