# Spring Boot Tomcat Configuration, migration from container to embedded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm migrating a Spring boot application that used to run in the Tomcat container to a Spring Boot application that runs an embedded Tomcat.
My old Tomcat configuration has these configurations in the server.xml:

```
<Connector 
    executor="tomcatThreadPool"
    port="8080"
    protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
    acceptCount="500"
    acceptorThreadCount="2"
    maxThreads="150"
    maxHttpHeaderSize="32768"
    maxHeaderCount="256"
    connectionTimeout="20000"
    maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
    redirectPort="8443"
    useComet="false"
    socket.appReadBufSize="87380"
    socket.rxBufSize="87380"
    socket.performanceConnectionTime="2"
    socket.performanceLatency="0"
    socket.performanceBandwidth="1"
    server="My server"
    />
```

I was able to set up most of the properties using a bean

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.setProtocol("org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol");
    tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers((TomcatConnectorCustomizer) connector -> {
        AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol<Nio2Channel> handler = (AbstractHttp11JsseProtocol)connector.getProtocolHandler();
        handler.setMaxKeepAliveRequests(-1);
        handler.setAcceptorThreadCount(2);
        handler.setMaxHeaderCount(256);
        connector.setRedirectPort(8443);
    });

    return tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
}
```

And application.xml properties:

```
server.tomcat.accept-count = 500
server.tomcat.max-threads = 600
server.port = 8080
server.max-http-header-size = 32768
server.connection-timeout = 20000
```

However I cannot figure out how to set this part

```
useComet="false"
socket.appReadBufSize="87380"
socket.rxBufSize="87380"
socket.performanceConnectionTime="2"
socket.performanceLatency="0"
socket.performanceBandwidth="1"
server="My server"
```

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
connector.setProperty("useComet", Boolean.toString(false));
connector.setProperty("socket.appReadBufSize", "87380");
connector.setProperty("socket.rxBufSize", "87380");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceConnectionTime", "2");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceLatency", "0");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceBandwidth", "1");
connector.setProperty("server", "My server");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
connector.setProperty("socket.appReadBufSize", "87380");
connector.setProperty("socket.rxBufSize", "87380");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceConnectionTime", "2");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceLatency", "0");
connector.setProperty("socket.performanceBandwidth", "1");
connector.setProperty("server", "My server");
```

Worked great. 
However it's important to check the return value of the connector.setProperty. It's trying to find the right method to call for every property, and returns true if the method was found and the property was set.
Unfortunately `connector.setProperty("useComet", Boolean.toString(false));` did not work, and returned false.