# How to increase the allowed number of headers in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

In one of my application, I am supposed to send a GET request which has more than 100 filter fields that I am supposed to pass. I get the following error when I send this GET request to one of my springboot applications

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: More than the maximum allowed number
>   of headers, [100], were detected.
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.createHeader(MimeHeaders.java:260)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.MimeHeaders.addValue(MimeHeaders.java:305)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeader(Http11InputBuffer.java:790)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseHeaders(Http11InputBuffer.java:565)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:703)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_152]
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_152]
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar!/:8.5.23]
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]

Request a way forward as I am stuck on this.

Comment: how you deployed the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is configured on you tomcat container. You could increase `maxHeaderCount` in **server.xml** in the Connector you are using. See [this](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html) for reference. If you have huge header size with so many headers, you might need to consider increasing `maxHttpHeaderSize` as well.

```
<Connector port="8080" maxHeaderCount="200" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ... />
```

With embedded tomcat you are using, you could do this programmatically.

```
  @Bean
  EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() throws Exception {
    return (ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) -> {
      if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat =
            (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
        tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
          Http11NioProtocol handler = (Http11NioProtocol) connector.getProtocolHandler();
          handler.setMaxHeaderCount(200); // set the number
        });
      }
    };
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way where I can set these in application.properties in Springboot?

Comment: Thank you. :)  The above one worked. It would be great if I could have the above as a configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are deploying and running the app in dedicated tomcat container(Not on docker or embed tomcat of spring-boot.

You can increase like this in server.xml file.

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" maxHeaderCount="300"/>
```

See this for the details:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html

Comment: Is there any way where I can set the maxHeaderCount in application properties of Springboot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44791514/spring-boot-tomcat-configuration-migration-from-container-to-embedded might help you

Comment: Thank you. :)  it worked..It would be great if I could have this as a configuration.